# String split and spread the result across different arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, linq

I have a string which gets the data in the following format

```
string str = "0,A 1,B 2,C 3,D 4,E";
```

How do i split this string in two different arrays **values** and **quads** such that

values array contains the following values :

```
values[0] = "0" 
values[1] = "1" 
values[2] = "2" 
values[3] = "3"
values[4] = "4"
```

and quads array contains

```
quads[0] = "A" 
quads[1] = "B" 
quads[2] = "C" 
quads[3] = "D"
quads[4] = "E"
```

str.Split(' ').ToArray() shall return me in this format

```
[0] = 0,A
[1] = 1,B
[2] = 2,C
[3] = 3,D
[4] = 4,E
```

I can enumerate this and populate in two different arrays in the format i need.

Is there a much shorter/simple way to do (using LINQ aggregates/Regex ) what I'm trying to achieve ?

Thanks

Thanks and Regards

Comment: show us what u have tried so far ??

Comment: Is the input always of the form 
{number column letter space}
, or is `str` just an example?

Comment: It was just an example. The data chunk I get is usually NUMBER COMMA DECIMAL SPACE format. However in erroneous situation I might just get letters as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from linq

```
var splitted = str.Split(' ');
var quads = splitted .Select(pair => pair.Split(',').Last()).ToArray();
var values = splitted .Select(pair => pair.Split(',').First()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way you can do it.

```
string str = "0,A 1,B 2,C 3,D 4,E"; 
var firstSplit = str.Split(" ".ToCharArray()) ; 

var values = firstSplit.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(",".ToCharArray())[0])).ToArray() ;
var quads = firstSplit.Select(s => s.Split(",".ToCharArray())[1]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Whilst this is correct, I would imagine for larger lists its much better to just traverse the list once, splitting once, and adding to both lists at the same time

Comment: So that case you can always foreach

Answer (score 2):

Split takes a char[], so you can split by space AND comma. (It also returns an array, so ToArray() is not necessary)

```
var split = str.Split(' ', ',')
    .Select(s => s[0]) //from string[] to char[]
    .GroupBy(char.IsDigit); //group by boolean
```

This should return 2 groups;
Then you can add `.Select(g => g.ToArray())` to get 2 string arrays.

Comment: Best Linq answer imo. Maybe use the method group to `GroupBy` instead: `.GroupBy(char.IsDigit)`

Answer (score 1):

here how you can get  your first two results

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "0,A 1,B 2,C 3,D 4,E";
            var values = str.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
            var quads  = str.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray();

        }
```

Comment: This one works as well. Sorry had to accept the first response from @shahar. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Using split string on the whitespace and afterwards on the , helps with splitting the string in pairs.

```
string str = "0,A 1,B 2,C 3,D 4,E";
var pairs = str.Split().Select(p => p.Split(',')).Select(p => new
                                                           {
                                                               Key = p[0],
                                                               Quad = p[1]
                                                           });
string[] keys = pairs.Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();
string[] quads = pairs.Select(p => p.Quad).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation in PHP:

```
$a = explode(" ", "0,A 1,B 2,C 3,D 4,E");

$vals = array();
$quads = array();
$tmp = array();
$i=0;
foreach ($a as $elem) {
   $tmp = explode(",",$elem);
   $vals[$i] = $tmp[0];
   $quads[$i] = $tmp[1];
   $i++;
}

//Note: use of incremental var $i to synchronize both arrays.
```

Output:

**vals array:**

Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 )

**quads array:**

Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D [4] => E )